# Miller Rabin Primality test

Tags: c#

I have wrote a Miller Rabin primality test in C sharp, but it return false on every input.

Here's the code:

```
    static Boolean MilRab(UInt64 n)
    {
        UInt64[] ar = new UInt64[] { 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29 };
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            if (Tanu(ar[i], n) == true) return false;
        }
        return true;
    }//MilRab

    static Boolean Tanu(UInt64 a, UInt64 n)
    {
        UInt64 b = n - 1;
        UInt64 d = 1;
        UInt64 x;
        Int16 i;
        for (i = 63; i >= 0; i--) if (((b >> i) & 1) == 1) break;

        for (;i>=0;i--)
        {
            x = d;
            d = ((d * d) % n);
            if (d == 1 && x != 1 && x != n - 1) return true;
            if (b>>i == 1) d = (d * a) % n;
        }
        if (d != 1) return true;
      return false;
    }//Tanu
```

What do you think the problem can be? I spent a hole day debugging and its driving me crazy. Thank you.

Comment: In `(d * d) % n` and `(d * a) % n`, the multiplication can (and often will) wrap modulo 2^64 before being reduced modulo `n`, which is incorrect (for almost all `n`).

Comment: I recommend using the `BigInteger` struct.

Comment: I used the BigInteger.Modpow and BigInteger multiplication and it is working perfectly. Thank You.

Comment: When posting code on SO, please try to keep significant variable names.

Answer (score 3):

Check this implementation for int and BigInteger

http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Miller-Rabin_primality_test#C.23

Answer (score 2):

As Amir said,

http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Miller-Rabin_primality_test#C.23

has the solution. But.. I tried it and even for very small input values like 79, it gives wrong results (79 is prime but comes out repeatedly as not prime). The reason is an overflow in the power (e. g. 11^78 is something like 1E+81, which is not representable by a 32 or 64bit integer).

So here

```
public static class RabinMiller
{
    public static bool IsPrime(int n, int k)
    {
        if(n < 2)
        {
            return false;
        }
        if(n != 2 && n % 2 == 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
        int s = n - 1;
        while(s % 2 == 0)
        {
            s >>= 1;
        }
        Random r = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
        {
            double a = r.Next((int)n - 1) + 1;
            int temp = s;
            int mod = (int)Math.Pow(a, (double)temp) % n;
            while(temp != n - 1 && mod != 1 && mod != n - 1)
            {
                mod = (mod * mod) % n;
                temp = temp * 2;
            }
            if(mod != n - 1 && temp % 2 == 0)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

you should add a function

```
    static int ModuloPower(int a, int b, int n)
    {
        // return (a^b)%n
        int res = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < b; ++i)
            res = (res * a) % n;
        return res;
    }
```

and change the power/modulo line to

```
    int mod = ModuloPower(a, temp, n); // (int)Math.Pow(a, (double)temp) % n;
```

This can of course be optimized again.. see code examples for other languages on the rosettacode site for some more clever ways to calculate the power/modulo faster.

(I tried editing code there but would have to sign up, so I post here.)

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to post the code *with* corrections, instead of the wrong code?

Comment: I noticed this fails over 46817... maybe another overflow somewhere.

Comment: @Sunsetquest The number you give is roughly 15.5 bits, so I think it might overflow with 32 bits (31 if you drop the sign). You could  make the "int res" an "int64 res" and should get a significantly larger number for this algorithm to work, or perhaps use uint64, I am not sure about C# naming, ulong should be correct.

Comment: You're right.  It now goes to at least 650,000 with Int64...probably much higher.

Comment: up to ~32 bits, so it should be roughly 4 billion, just looking at that one place. (or 31.5 bits for signed int64)

Comment: fyi, I applied your fixes with some other code updates at the rosettacode site site http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Miller-Rabin_primality_test#C.23.